# How can I preview the Drupal page as specific users?

Tags: 7

I just started using Drupal, so I'm still learning myself how to configure it. I have seen some older tutorials where there's a module(?) installed where you can click on "Hello %user%" in the top right corner and select which user you want to preview the page as. Is there a module for this or some built in setting I have overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module called [masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) can do it. Not sure if it is the one you are refering to though.

> The masquerade module is designed as a tool for site designers and
>   site administrators. It allows a user with the right permissions to
>   switch users. While masquerading, a field is set on the $user object,
>   and a menu item appears allowing the user to switch back. Watchdog
>   entries are made any time a user masquerades or stops masquerading.